# Can anyone help me with logic to understand this loop?

Tags: python-3.x

```
sharks = ['hammerhead', 'great white', 'dogfish', 'frilled', 'bullhead', 'requiem']

for item in range(len(sharks)):
   sharks.append('shark')

print(sharks)
```

I somehow understood it but it's not that clear yet.

```
['hammerhead', 'great white', 'dogfish', 'frilled', 'bullhead', 'requiem', 'shark', 'shark', 'shark', 'shark', 'shark', 'shark']
```

Comment: Your question needs more clarification. Are you wondering why shark is appending 6 times? Well that's because you loop over sharks which has 6 elements and you repeatedly append it. If you want to append shark to each element of the `list`, do not use append, modify that element directly.

Comment: `list.append()` will add a new element to `sharks`. If you did `sharks.append('test'), you will see: `['hammerhead', 'great white', 'dogfish', 'frilled', 'bullhead', 'requiem', 'test']

Answer (score 1):

It's simply adding a new element, the string'shark', to the sharks array for each item in the original array.

If you actually want to append 'shark' to each existing element you could use this.

```
sharks = ['hammerhead', 'great white', 'dogfish', 'frilled', 'bullhead', 'requiem']

sharks = [f'{shark} shark' for shark  in sharks]

print(sharks)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of 6 sharks.  The for loop can be translated in english like this: for the length of our sharks list (which is 6 because it contains 6 elements) add the string "shark" to the sharks list.

Since len(sharks) == 6 the for loop will be executed 6 times and the string "shark" will be added 6 times to your sharks list.

Afterwards, the code says to print the list with print(sharks) which now contains your initial list + 6 "shark" strings.